# Classifying a degenerate point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the function $$f(x, y)=y^4-4y^3+x^2y-x^2-2y^2+12y-7$$
I found that the function has three critical points: $(0, 3)$, $(0, 1)$ and $(0, -1)$. I'm now trying to classify the degenerate point $(0, 1)$ by considering the value of $f$ along the curve $y=cx^2+1$ for different values of c.

Substituting $y=cx^2+1$ into $f$ gives: $$f(x, cx^2+1)=cx^4-8c^2x^4+c^4x^8$$

The second derivative is: $$12cx^2-96c^2x^2+56c^4x^6$$

However, substituting $x=0$ into the second derivative gives $0$, which tells us nothing about whether the degenerate critical point is a local maximum or a local minimum.

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can’t you examine the eigenvalues of the Jacobian (which is diagonal) to classify the point?

Comment: @amd. I tried examining whether the Hessian (the derivative of the Jacobian) was either positive definite or negative definite, but I got that it was neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hessian $H$ at $\mathbf p=(0,1)^T$ is equal to $\operatorname{diag}(0,-16)$. This is singular, but it’s also negative semidefinite and useful information about this critical point can be gleaned from it. Obviously, its eigenvalues are $0$ and $-16$, with the standard basis vectors as corresponding eigenvectors. Examining the second eigenpair, we can see that the restriction of $f$ to the line $x=0$ has a local maximum at $\mathbf p$. Looking in the $x$-direction, we observe that $f(x,1)=0$: the function is constant in that direction. The second-order Taylor approximation to $f$ at $\mathbf p$ is $$f(\mathbf x)=(\mathbf x-\mathbf p)^TH(\mathbf x-\mathbf p)+O(\|\mathbf x-\mathbf p\|^3) = -16(y-1)^2 + O(\|\mathbf x-\mathbf p\|^3),$$ which is nonpositive for points close enough to $\mathbf p$, so I’d be inclined to say that $f$ has a kind of local maximum at $\mathbf p$.